# Gecko Webbrowser Load Links Inside Another Gecko Browser (Same Form)

Tags: vb.net

So I am trying to implement a system into my program and when a link is pressed inside the gecko browser it will send the link clicked to anther gecko browser rather than opening the default internet (eg. Internet Explorer) and continuing from there.

TD;LR: Click Gecko Browser, link opens in anther Gecko Browser.

Diagram: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5eN9f.png

Comment: What's your question? Are you having trouble with an aspect of this?

Comment: I know how to solve your issue, but the *CLICK HERE TO WIN* makes it very suspicious and I don't want to help a spammer or scammer. Would you mind elaborating on that image?

Comment: It's abolutely not necessary to SHOUT YOUR QUESTIONS here. We can all see just fine when you use your Shift key properly. Please don't post in ALL CAPS. It's annoying, and won't get you help any faster. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for using CAPS. Why does CLICK HERE TO WIN make it suspicious? The reason for that is because I am making a program which you complete surveys to get points and stuff. But besides that it is something that would be vital if I were to create a web-browser.

Comment: First off Gecko isn't a browser, it's a layout engine, upon which you can build a browser.  Is this what you intend to build a browser based app?  Where is your code with explanations on where it is going wrong?  Basically, you need to trap the link and open your window with the information you want.

Comment: I have tried many things but I just get errors because I have no idea how to use Gecko. Please help, I have been searching for hours!